# Vector graphics with ITextSharp

Tags: vector, pdf-generation, itext

I have heard that ITextSharp does not have support for the JAVA2D class, does this mean that i cant import vector points from a clients databas to "print" to a ITextSharp application?

I would relly like to find answer to this before going further with this suggestion. 
Anyone have real experiences of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is true that you can't use JAVA2D with iTextSharp you can still draw vector graphics in a PDF-native way by writing directly to the `PdfWriter.DirectContent` object. It supports all of the standard `MoveTo()`, `LineTo()`, `CurveTo()`, etc methods that you'd expect from a vector drawing program. Below is a full-working VB.Net WinForms app targeting iTextSharp 5.1.1.0 the shows off some simple uses.

```
Option Explicit On
Option Strict On

Imports iTextSharp.text
Imports iTextSharp.text.pdf
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim OutputFile As String = Path.Combine(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop, "VectorTest.pdf")

        Using FS As New FileStream(OutputFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None)
            Using Doc As New Document(PageSize.LETTER)
                Using writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(Doc, FS)
                    ''//Open the PDF for writing
                    Doc.Open()

                    Dim cb As PdfContentByte = writer.DirectContent

                    ''//Save the current state so that we can restore it later. This is not required but it makes it easier to undo things later
                    cb.SaveState()

                    ''//Draw a line with a bunch of options set
                    cb.MoveTo(100, 100)
                    cb.LineTo(500, 500)
                    cb.SetRGBColorStroke(255, 0, 0)
                    cb.SetLineWidth(5)
                    cb.SetLineDash(10, 10, 20)
                    cb.SetLineCap(PdfContentByte.LINE_CAP_ROUND)
                    cb.Stroke()

                    ''//This undoes any of the colors, widths, etc that we did since the last SaveState
                    cb.RestoreState()

                    ''//Draw a circle
                    cb.SaveState()
                    cb.Circle(200, 500, 50)
                    cb.SetRGBColorStroke(0, 255, 0)
                    cb.Stroke()

                    ''//Draw a bezier curve
                    cb.RestoreState()
                    cb.MoveTo(100, 300)
                    cb.CurveTo(140, 160, 300, 300)
                    cb.SetRGBColorStroke(0, 0, 255)
                    cb.Stroke()

                    ''//Close the PDF
                    Doc.Close()
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub
End Class
```

**EDIT**

Incidentally, although you can't use JAVA2D (which is obviously Java and wouldn't work with .Net) you can create iTextSharp images using the standard `System.Drawing.Image` class and passing it to `iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance()` static method. Unfortunately `System.Drawing.Image` is a raster/bitmap object so it won't help you in this case.

Comment: Thank you very much for making such a nice example and answering my question. It will make my job easier! I think i will use ITextSharp now for an upcoming project. / R