# PdfContentByte.createGraphicsShapes(...) in iTextSharp?

Tags: c#, graphics, itext

How can I get the C# winform graphics system from iTextSharp?

So that I can use `DrawString(....)` to draw text directly onto the existed PDF.

Comment: This question isn't off-topic. I recommended the person posting this to post this on SO. See http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.lib.itext.general/66010

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this isn't possible right now. iText, the Java-based library, subclassed the system class `java.awt.Graphics2D` which is a further subclass of `java.awt.Graphics`. This allowed them to bridge Sun/Oracle's drawing paradigms with their own. iTextSharp was ported from Java to C# but for whatever reason the system `Graphics` bridging code was not ported.

If I were to guess Java and .Net's version of `Graphics` were too dissimilar and there just wasn't enough community desire to bother with it. Also, .Net's implementation has extra abstractions like `Pen` and `Brush` so this would have made the bridge code very different between the Java and .Net version. Not to mention methods like `FillPie()`, `MeasureString()`, etc.

Right now your two main options are to either [just manually draw to the `PdfContentByte`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7344437/vector-graphics-with-itextsharp/7348750#7348750) object which, once you get used to the inverted axis (Adobe's fault, not iText), goes pretty easy, or you can draw to a .Net image and then just embed it. If you do the latter, I'd recommend at least tripling the image resolution and then embedding it at a third of the size, effectively kicking up the DPI.

You can also try something like [PDFsharp](http://www.pdfsharp.net/) which, according to their site, has a very native feel for drawing.